# Dagger 2 share object instance between presenters

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am developing an application that has a few services, including a `FirebaseAuthService`.  I would like to have the same `FirebaseAuthService` instance in all of my presenters (for each activity).  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `@Singleton` annotation if you want the instance to be the same for your whole application. 
Or you can create your own scope, for example `@ActivityScope` to create instances that are 'singletons' to one activity. 
[This](https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-part-i-basic-principles-graph-dependencies-scopes-3dfd032ccd82) should give you a good starting point.